# Random square submatrices of a Hadamard matrix

Tags: fourier-analysis, random-matrices

**Question:** For $N$ be a power of $2$, let $A$ be a random $d \times d$ submatrix of the $N \times N$ [Hadamard matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix) (the matrix of the Hadamard/Walsh-Fourier transform).  What is the best known upper bound on the probability that $A$ is singular?  The range of $d$ I'm asking about is, say, $\log N \leq d \leq N^{0.001}$.

**Other stuff:**
One might hope that there is a universal constant $c < 1$ such that the probability is at most $c^d$.  I'm not even close to this: at the risk of asking a trivial question, is it known or straightforward to show that the probability goes to $0$ as $N$ (and thus $d$) approach $\infty$?

A couple things that I am aware of:

- If $d$ is "small" (certainly at most $\frac12\log N$; maybe a more stringent bound is required), then [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895688900408) of Frankl, Rödl, and Wilson says that the distribution of $A$ is very close to that of a random matrix with i.i.d. uniform $\pm 1$ entries.
- For non-square random submatrices, [this book chapter](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/non-asymptotic-rmt-plain.pdf) by Vershynin has a few results.  This case is pretty interesting in compressed sensing and well-studied in terms of restricted isometry properties.  However, I have been unable to find anything that applies to the case of square random submatrices.

Comment: When N > 20 one likely has many choices for the matrix, which distribution and structure are largely unknown.  Are you making any assumptions on N  or on the distribution of the Hadamard matrices of that order?

Comment: I followed the link, so it become clear you want N a power of 2.  For clarity, you might edit the post to make that explicit.  Also, the more general form is of interest. ( I see that it is explicit.  Thank you.)